# Making a clickable grid using Pygame

Tags: python, pygame, grid

I'm making a minesweeper game using python. I have the game working in a text only form and I'm adding a GUI now.

I have three difficulty options with different dimensions. Is there any way to generate a grid without having to make it manually. This is how I generated a square matrix in text form:

```
for count in range(side):
    count2 = 0
    temp1 = []
    temp2 = []
    for count2 in range(side):
        temp1.append(0)
        temp2.append("x")
    grid.append(temp1)
    field.append(temp2)
    count+=1
```

Is there any way to automatically generate a grid like this in pygame? I am also using custom sprites and every cell needs to be clickable. Will I just have to make the grids manually and use them according to the difficulty?

Comment: You have to be more specific. What have you tried so far? Where do you struggle?

Comment: *"Is there any way to generate a grid without having to make it manually?"* - No, there is no bot that will do it for you. You have to code it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no simple solution to draw a grid. You have to loop over each cell as you did in your example. You can find all functions to draw in the [pygame wiki](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html).

Example for grid creation:

```
size = (100, 100)
cell_width = 10
cell_height = 10

grid_surface = pygame.Surface(size) # here you draw
grid = [] # simple list to save your data

for x in range(side):
    grid.append([]) # new column for the list
    
    for y in range(side):
        # save data to grid
        grid[x][y] = "x"

        # draw something
        # e.g.: this draws a red rectangle in each cell
        pygame.draw.rect(grid_surface, (200, 0, 0), (x * cell_width, y * cell_height, cell_width, cell_height)
```

Potential event loop:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        running = False
    elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        x, y = (event.pos[0] // cell_width, event.pos[1] // cell_height)

        # do something
        print(grid[x][y])
        grid[x][y] = "a"

        pygame.draw.rect(grid_surface, (0, 200, 0), (x * cell_width, y * cell_height, cell_width, cell_height)
```

Comment: Thanks! Getting mouse position and dividing it with the cell width, after adjusting the offsets of the padding on each side, will do it for me, i think i won't use my button class for this and instead of registering clicks on each individual cell i'll register clicks using coordinates to determine the cell.

Comment: @SXH7 Of course, you should register clicks using coordinates. However, you should use a class to represent the state and attributes of the cell. You need to know if the cell has been clicked and you need to know if there is a mine in the cell.

Comment: @Rabbid76 i have all of that worked out as i did make it in text form, this was the one part in gui i needed help with

Answer (score 2):

I came across a similar issue, here is the solution I found worked well and is fairly simple to implement.

```
gridstate = {}
class Button:
def __init__(self, x, y, w, h, *get_co, action=False):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.w = w
    self.h = h
    self.get_co = get_co
    self.colour = (255, 255, 255)
    self.clicked = False
    self.box = py.draw.rect(screen, self.colour, (x, y, w, h))
    self.action = action

def draw(self):
    pos = py.mouse.get_pos()
    if self.box.collidepoint(pos):
        if py.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 1 and self.clicked == False:
            self.clicked = True
            if self.action == False:
                self.action = True
                self.colour = (255, 0, 0)
            elif self.action == True:
                self.action = False
                self.colour = (255, 255, 255)
    if py.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 0:
        self.clicked = False
    self.box = py.draw.rect(screen, self.colour,
                            (self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h))
    gridstate.update({self.get_co: self.action})
    return self.action
```

I created the class for the button as above, this accepts the argument "get_co" to which I put the 'co ordinate' relative to the rest of the grid so I am able to identify which button was pressed. I pass in the data in like so - This creates a 10x10 grid

```
resx = 10
resy = 10
buttonsize = 25
grid = []

for x in range(resx):
for y in range(resy):
    grid.append(Button((x*buttonsize), (y*buttonsize),
                       buttonsize, buttonsize, x, y))
```

Within the loop of game I simply run

```
activecells = []
for key, value in gridstate.items():
    if value == True:
        activecells.append(key)
```

To find the clicked buttons and add them to a list to reference later.

```
for row in grid:
    row.draw()
```

To draw the grid to the screen.

This seemed to do the trick for me. Apologies ahead of time for any actual programmers who will probably be horrified by my variable naming!

Answer (score 0):

I will give you a very simple start. You should create a class that represents a cell in the grid. Create a matrix of cells to represent your board:

```py
class Cell:
    def __init__(self):
        self.clicked = False

grid_size = 10
board = [[Cell() for _ in range(grid_size)] for _ in range(grid_size)]
```

Calculate the index of a cell when the mouse button is clicked and change the attributes in the cell:

```py
for event in pygame.event.get():
    # [...]

    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        if event.button == 1:
            row = event.pos[1] // 20
            col = event.pos[0] // 20
            board[row][col].clicked = True
```

Draw the board in 2 nested loops:

```py
for iy, rowOfCells in enumerate(board):
    for ix, cell in enumerate(rowOfCells):
        color = (64, 64, 64) if cell.clicked else (164, 164, 164)
        pygame.draw.rect(window, color, (ix*20, iy*20, 20, 20))
```

---

Minimal example:

[image]

```py
import pygame

class Cell:
    def __init__(self):
        self.clicked = False

grid_size = 10
board = [[Cell() for _ in range(grid_size)] for _ in range(grid_size)]

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((200, 200))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(100)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False 
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:    
            if event.button == 1:
                row = event.pos[1] // 20
                col = event.pos[0] // 20
                board[row][col].clicked = True

    window.fill(0)
    for iy, rowOfCells in enumerate(board):
        for ix, cell in enumerate(rowOfCells):
            color = (64, 64, 64) if cell.clicked else (164, 164, 164)
            pygame.draw.rect(window, color, (ix*20+1, iy*20+1, 18, 18))
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```